# Rotate camera with mouse?

Tags: c++

Once again, using tutorial 10 at NeHe.

I want the code

```
if (keys[VK_RIGHT])                         // Is The Right Arrow Being Pressed?
{
    yrot -= 1.5f;                           // Rotate The Scene To The Left
}

if (keys[VK_LEFT])                          // Is The Left Arrow Being Pressed?
{
    yrot += 1.5f;                           // Rotate The Scene To The Right   
}
```

and

```
if (keys[VK_PRIOR])
 {
    lookupdown -= 1.0f;
 }

if (keys[VK_NEXT])
 {
    lookupdown += 1.0f;
 }
```

to be done with the mouse instead of left/right arrow and Page Up/ Page Down. I tried everything I could think of. Can anyone help?

EDIT: I tried using WM_MOUSEMOVE message. I just could not figure it out.

EDIT2: I am using pure OpenGL to do this. No window management system or other libs such as GLUT, GLFW, SDL, SFML etc. Just OpenGL. OpenGL and GLEW.

EDIT: Issue has been solved.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you tell us which ways of handling the mouse you tried before posting on this site?

Comment: Needs more detail. What window-management API are you using? (GLUT, GTK, Win32, X11?) Or maybe a higher-level framework like SDL or Allegro? The solution depends on that. (Assuming from "NeHe tutorials" that you're using OpenGL.)

Comment: I am indeed using pure OpenGL. Edited now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it using **Win32 API** then here's code :

```
// the Windows Procedure event handler
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        // save old mouse coordinates
        oldMouseX = mouseX;
        oldMouseY = mouseY;

        // get mouse coordinates from Windows
        mouseX = LOWORD(lParam);
        mouseY = HIWORD(lParam);

        // these lines limit the camera's range
        if (mouseY < 200)
            mouseY = 200;
        if (mouseY > 450)
            mouseY = 450;

        if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) > 0)             // mouse moved to the right
            angle += 3.0f;
        else if ((mouseX - oldMouseX) < 0)     // mouse moved to the left
            angle -= 3.0f;

        return 0;
        break;
```

Now in your rendering function do this :

```
void Render()
{
    radians =  float(PI*(angle-90.0f)/180.0f);

    // calculate the camera's position
    cameraX = lookX + sin(radians)*mouseY;     // multiplying by mouseY makes the
    cameraZ = lookZ + cos(radians)*mouseY;    // camera get closer/farther away with mouseY
    cameraY = lookY + mouseY / 2.0f;

    //... your drawing code below this ...
```

Full code for above project can be found here : https://code.google.com/p/dino-game-engine/source/browse/trunk/KLAB/terrain/?r=179#terrain%2FOPENGLTG_Src%2FCode

If you are using **GLUT** then here's code for that : http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glut-tutorial/mouse-putting-it-all-together/